# $1 of nonterminal has no declared type

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
%}

%start INPUT
%union {int num}
%token <num> val
%type <num>SUM

%%
INPUT: SUM

SUM: '('SUM '+' SUM')'  {$$ = $1 + $2}
    | val               {$$ = $1}

%%

int main(){
    return yyparse();
}
```

I am trying to make a parser. Although I declare the type for SUM nonterminal, it gives me the warning:

```
error: $1 of ‘SUM’ has no declared type
 SUM: '('SUM '+' SUM')'  {$$ = $1 + $2}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SUM: '('SUM '+' SUM')'  {$$ = $1 + $2}
```

Here `$1` refers to `'('` and `$2` refers to `SUM`. So when bsion complains that `$1` has no declared type, that means that the `'('` token has no declared type, which is true.

Of course you don't want to add the `'('` token to anything, you want to add the two sums. For that you should add `$2` and `$4`.

To avoid these kind of indexing mistakes, you could also consider using [named references](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Named-References.html) like this:

```
SUM: '(' SUM[left] '+' SUM[right] ')'  { $$ = $left + $right; }
```